# Upgrading a Stripe Subscription from a $0 Product Price

Tags: java, stripe-payments

Suppose I have a subscription product in Stripe, with two prices:

1. Free - $0 monthly
2. Basic = $5 monthly

When a new user signs up on my site, I assign them the Free plan automatically.

After some time, a user may decide to upgrade to the Basic plan to get more functionality.  It's unclear to me how to do this.  If I create a checkout session and add the $5 price to that session, the user is able to enter payment information and check out, but the user now has two subscriptions. Like this:

```
SessionCreateParams params = new SessionCreateParams.Builder()
    .setSuccessUrl("http://localhost:4200/bill/plan-changed")                                    
    .setCancelUrl("http://localhost:4200/bill/canceled")
    .setCustomer(customerId) // id of previously created Stripe Customer
    .setMode(Mode.SUBSCRIPTION)
    .addLineItem(new Builder()
        .setQuantity(1L)
        .setPrice(subscriptionPriceId) // id of $5 Basic Price
        .build())
    .build();
return Session.create(params);
```

The behavior I want is for the original Free subscription to be ended/canceled, and for the new $5 plan to replace it.  How do I do that?

Comment: Since the basic package is free of charge, you could completely ignore that and have just one optional package to pay. Or you could treat both as separate products. Or... Whatever decision you take - it is not a programming problem.

Comment: The free package ("price" in Stripe parlance) contains metadata that my application needs in order to function.  I need the $0 price.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout as a product can only be used to accept a payment or start a brand new Subscription. So you can't use this for the "upgrade" flow.

The easiest option is to use Stripe's [Customer Portal](https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management) which allows your customer to see their Subscription(s). It also supports upgrades so you can configure the portal to allow going from the free to the paid Price easily.

Alternatively, you would build your own UI that would ask the customer if they want to switch to a paid Price. If so, your code would use the Update Subscription [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) to swap their Price. This is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  I was able to upgrade/downgrade the subscription by configuring the customer portal with two products ($0; $5) having the same recurrence periods.  I can also add payment methods here.  I will start with this and then potentially build my own UI as you suggest.